# access to activemq statistics plugin in C# .NET

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

I am trying to access the activemq statistics  int C# taking this example:

http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html

Y tried many ways but my received MapMessage is null or throw exception like "cannot convert AMQMessage to MapMessage"

this is my class:

```
public class Statistics
{
    private readonly IConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private readonly IConnection connection;
    private readonly ISession session;

    public Statistics( string brokerUri)
    {
        this.connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(brokerUri);
        this.connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        this.connection.Start();
        this.session = connection.CreateSession();
    }

    public void GetStats()
    {
        // Crear consumidor


        try
        {
            // Creo una cola y consumidor
            IDestination queueReplyTo = session.CreateTemporaryQueue();
            IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(queueReplyTo);


            // Crear cola  y productor
            ActiveMQQueue newQueue = new ActiveMQQueue("ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination.TEST1");
            IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(null);

            // Crear cola monitorizada
            string listeningQueue = "TEST1";
            ActiveMQQueue query = new ActiveMQQueue(listeningQueue);

            // Mandar mensaje vacío y replicar
            IMessage msg = session.CreateMessage();
            producer.Send(newQueue, msg);
            msg.NMSReplyTo = queueReplyTo;
            producer.Send(query, msg);

            // Recibir
            IMapMessage reply = (IMapMessage)consumer.ReceiveNoWait();


            if (reply != null)
            {
                IPrimitiveMap statsMap = reply.Body;

                foreach (string statKey in statsMap.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", statKey, statsMap[statKey]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var t = e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace;
        }
    }


}
```

Where is my erroris my error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

```
public class Statistics
{
    private readonly IConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private readonly IConnection connection;
    private readonly ISession session;

    public Statistics( string brokerUri)
    {
        this.connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(brokerUri);
        this.connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        this.connection.Start();
        this.session = connection.CreateSession();
    }

    public void GetStats()
    {
        // Crear consumidor


        try
        {
            // Creo una cola y consumidor
            IDestination queueReplyTo = session.CreateTemporaryQueue();
            IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(queueReplyTo);

            // Crear cola monitorizada
            string listeningQueue = "TEST1";
            ActiveMQQueue testQueue  =  session.GetQueue(listeningQueue);


            // Crear cola  y productor
            ActiveMQQueue query =  session.GetQueue("ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination.TEST1");
            IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(null);

            // Mandar mensaje vacío y replicar
            IMessage msg = session.CreateMessage();
            producer.Send(testQueue, msg);
            msg.NMSReplyTo = queueReplyTo;
            producer.Send(query, msg);

            // Recibir
            IMapMessage reply = (IMapMessage)consumer.Receive();


            if (reply != null)
            {
                IPrimitiveMap statsMap = reply.Body;

                foreach (string statKey in statsMap.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", statKey, statsMap[statKey]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var t = e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I think that messages to the "queueReplyTo" are automatically sended when a message is sended to the others declared queues.

I dont know how 'statistics' works and i dont find information of how to use it in .NET

Comment: i think you need to read carefully http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html to understand the concept. I updated my response with c# code

Comment: "CreateQueue" is not in ISession API

Comment: try with GetQueue

Comment: consumer.Receive() is waiting infinitely.  No messages in 'queueReplyTo' queue.... i dont understand when a message is sended to 'queueReplyTo' and who do it?

Comment: I hope thay you have enabled this <broker ...>
  <plugins>
    <statisticsBrokerPlugin/>
  </plugins>
</broker>

Comment: If plugin is enabled i think you have to set a string property "JMSReplyTo" with value "TEST1" to the message

Comment: Message is sent immediately by the broker to queueReplyTo

Comment: Here is another question for the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746391/how-to-access-the-activemq-statistics-plugin-in-net?rq=1

Comment: Hassen Bennour where must i add that plugin ? in app.config of my project ?