# Connect to Active MQ via c# to Find Consumers

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

Is there a way in C# to  do following

a) Connect to AMQ

b) Find All Queues

c) For each Queue, find the count of consumers and Id/Name of Consumer

d) For each Queue, find the count of produces and Id/Name of Producer

I have used NMS but it does not give me a way of finding Consumer count for a Queue or name of the consumer.

[image]

As you can see from the image, i have a queue and have 5 consumers connected to that queue. I need to be able to find the count and also the names.

Thanks,
Zaeem

Answer (score 0):

Since C# applications won't be able to connect to the Broker's JMX monitoring features you are left with solutions that involve NMS API code and a bit of broker configuration.  There are two features of the broker that should allow you to mostly figure out what you need, the first is [Advisory Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) and the second is the [Statistics Plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) feature.

With the advisory support enabled broker side your client could subscribe to the advisory Topic for Queue create / destroy and keep a cache of active destinations on the broker.  Then you can use the query feature of the statistics plugin to query on the state of a given Queue as needed.

Comment: so im able to connect to AMQ but again i cannot find a way progamatically to find information about a existing queue and consumer on that queue.

Comment: Below is the code snippet i managed to find but this creates temp queue and a producer and consumer. All i want is to find existing queue information and its consumer count and Name [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746391/how-to-access-the-activemq-statistics-plugin-in-net?rq=1

Comment: The code given is your only option, C# clients can't talk to JMX Mbeans so you have to use the statistics broker plugin feature to query for info on a destination.  There's no other answer here, features don't appear as if by magic when you want them to.

Comment: sorry im a bit new to c# and AMQ. do you know how to use statistics broker plugin to query that ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this done by calling the admin.bat file on AMQ Server in the end